# Can i get email notification from App Store when my app is downloaded from app store?

Tags: app-store

Is there any way that Apple can send us a notification email every time a user downloads our app from App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  But you can use [App Analytics](https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/), [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), or a third-party service such as [App Annie](https://www.appannie.com), which can email you daily summaries.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create a webservices rest and in your method DidFinishLaunching you save when your app is the first Open.. save open with the boolean value in NSUserDefaults and call your API.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might already do this if you buy a paid app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).